# is the UPDATEIFCOPY flag ever True?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to deeper understand numpy arrays; in particular memory layout / ownership / sharing related aspects. In that endeavour I stumbled across the UPDATEIFCOPY flag which sounds intriguing.
Only I've never actually seen it set.
The user can only [unset](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html) it. And googling "UPDATEIFCOPY True" is very relaxing if you like it quiet.

So how can I create an array with that flag set at True?

Comment: I think the UPDATEIFCOPY mechanism is supposed to be used internally only. So in the numpy source code or in C extensions. Having such an array on the Python side would be very unfriendly to users. One important use case within numpy seems to be handling `out` arguments that are misaligned, of an incorrect data type, or not C-contiguous see [code-explanations.rst](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/doc/source/reference/internals.code-explanations.rst).

Comment: @user7138814 After such a long time a coherent answer. Thank you very much, indeed! So it's that simple. But what about that example MSeifert dug out for his answer?

Comment: I guess when you pass the `'updateifcopy'` flag to `nditer` you're supposed to know what you're doing ;-) The first two lines in the example create a misaligned array, while the `nditer` commands an aligned array. So it works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set if when you use [`np.nditer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) (example taken from [NumPy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/core/tests/test_nditer.py#L806)):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((6*4+1,), dtype='i1')[1:]
>>> a.dtype = 'f4'
>>> a[:] = np.arange(6, dtype='f4')
>>> i = np.nditer(a, [], [['readwrite', 'updateifcopy', 'aligned']])
>>> print(i.operands[0].flags)
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : True     # <--- :-)
```

However I don't know under what circumstances this is really set because if I remove the first two lines then it doesn't work anymore:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.arange(6, dtype='f4')
>>> i = np.nditer(a, [], [['readwrite', 'updateifcopy', 'aligned']])
>>> print(i.operands[0].flags)
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False     # <--- :-(
```

Comment: Technically, that answers my question, so I've accepted it. I think taking both answers together I might be able to work it out once my brain stops spinning.

Answer (score 2):

The UPDATEIFCOPY flag can never be set to True.

**UPDATE**

If an array does not own its own memory, then the base attribute returns the object whose memory this array is referencing.

The returned object may not be the original allocator of the memory, but may be borrowing it from still another object. If this array does own its own memory, then None is returned unless the UPDATEIFCOPY flag is True in which case self.base is the array that will be updated when self is deleted.

UPDATEIFCOPY gets set automatically for an array that is created as a behaved copy of a general array. The intent is for the misaligned array to get any changes that occur to the copy.

Comment: You're doing this on purpose aren't you? I take it asking for a human readable version is out of the question? Anyway, here, have an upvote for your troubles ;-)

Comment: I guess I cannot make it any easier, english is not my primary language so it will be very difficult :)