# Python Numpy memory layout

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run a code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3,2))
b = a.T.reshape(3*2)
b[0] = 99
a
array([[0,0],
       [0,0],
       [0,0]])
```

The question here is that the reshape function in numpy return a view of the original array and if any changes occurs in view object or in main object would be propogated throughout the views and main object.

But in the above stated case it is not happening. Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

The last reshape you are doing can't be expressed in strides in the original memory layout:

```
orig                  1 2  3 4  5 6  ok, strides 2, 1

transpose             1 3 5  2 4 6   ok, strides 1, 2

reshaped transpose    1 3 5 2 4 6    impossible
```

I'm not 100% sure I understand this correctly (or, more precisely, I'm almost 100% sure I don't), but there may be some [obscure cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41952401/7207392) when a copy writes back. In any case, this is not one of them.

Comment: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]])    
then a.T gives 
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [2, 4, 5]])   
and then 
a.T.reshape(3,2) gives
 array([[1, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 5]])   
reshaping occurs but not in exact proper format  I am not getting why this happens

Comment: The numbers I've written are not referring to the values but to the memory locations. Memory is linear, any multidimenional array is ravelled to a 1d set of memory addresses. To keep that manageable every dimension gets a _stride_. cell (2,4) of the array lies at memory location array_base + stride0 x 2 + stride1 x 4. A new array will normally be C-contiguous, i.e. the last stride will be 1, the last but one shape[-1] etc. Taking the tranpose swaps stride0 and stride1. A 1d array has only stride0. The schematic demonstrates why the original layout doesn't accomodate the flattened transpose.

Answer (score 1):

The [official document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) gives an answer to your question.

> This will be a new view object if possible; otherwise, it will be a copy. Note there is no guarantee of the memory layout (C- or Fortran- contiguous) of the returned array.

Comment: if it creates a view of it then np.may_share_memory should return true but in the case of my question it is returning false i dont know why however if in reshape function instead of writting like (3*2) if u write (3,2) the np.may_share_memory function return true. I am not very sure but it is my guess that there is something related to 3*2  that makes a copy of it I guess

Answer (score 1):

From the `reshape` docs

> You can think of reshaping as first raveling the array (using the given index order), then inserting the elements from the raveled array into the new array using the same kind of index ordering as was used for the raveling

`transpose` is a view, but changes shape, strides, and order.  You get the elements in the original order by going down columns instead of across rows.  But now try flattening that transpose - in order C.  The elements will be shuffled.  Original 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... becomes 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 ...  You can't get that order without copying.

```
In [48]: a=np.arange(1,7).reshape(3,2)
In [49]: a
Out[49]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

The `arange` produced `[1,2,3....]`.  That data buffer is still used for `a`, and you can 'recover' it by reading across rows.

```
In [50]: b = a.T
In [51]: b
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

Transpose is produced by changing shape, strides and order.  It is now order='F'.  (I could show this with `.flags` and `.__array_interface__`.  It's a view, and still shares the original `arange` values.  Only now, because of the strides and order, you read down the columns.

```
In [52]: c = b.reshape(3,2)
In [53]: c
Out[53]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 2],
       [4, 6]])
```

This has same shape, strides, and 'C' order as `a`.  But the data buffer is a reordered copy of the original `[1,3,5,2..]`.  That's the same order as you'd get from `b` by reading across rows.

---

Another way to look at the reordering in `c` is to trace the original element order 1,2,3...

```
[0,0],[1,1],[0,1],[2,0],[1,0],[2,1]
```

Or with 2 index lists:

```
In [57]: a[[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,1,0,1,0,1]]    # regular pattern
Out[57]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [58]: b[[0,1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1,2,2]]    # same, switch order
Out[58]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [59]: c[[0,1,0,2,1,2],[0,1,1,0,0,1]]    # a jumble
Out[59]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: I'm totally agreed with that transpose share the memory space. a shares the memory with b but why b does not share space with c.

Comment: On the 2d displays of `a`,`b` and `c`,  trace out 1,2,3... On 2 of those that's a simple zigzag pattern.  But on `c` it's a mess - diagonal,up,double diagonal etc.  `numpy` can't use strides and shape to produce `c` from the original 1,2,3...

Comment: Causerie of which c gets a separate memory..Right   Ok!!